# Reference Google calendar items in desktop Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, google-calendar

Does anyone know a way to dynamically include my personal Google calendar when I view my work Outlook calendar.

The times allocated from my personal Google calendar should -not- include any information about the event; only that the time is allocated. I share my Outlook calendar with coworkers who do not need to know my personal activities. It might be useful to me to see calendar item titles, but I do not want to share that with coworkers. It is enough to see that time is allocated when I view the Outlook calendar. I can easily look at my Google calendar on my cell phone, a tablet, or other device.

I do not need to add or edit Google calendar items from Outlook. I only want to see them.

I do not want to import a static .ics file. It should dynamically update from the Google calendar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, it is recommended that you could try to subscribe to your Gmail account. For more details, refer to: [Subscribe to your Google Calendar](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/see-your-google-calendar-in-outlook-c1dab514-0ad4-4811-824a-7d02c5e77126#:%7E:text=Subscribe%20to%20your%20Google%20Calendar). Hope to help you!